# Request reflection matrix about these types

Tags: matrices, analytic-geometry, transformation

Supposed there's $(a,b)$ point and going to be reflected and find the mapping. The baseline formula will I use is
$\begin{pmatrix}
x' \\ 
y' \end{pmatrix}=M_{R}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ 
y \end{pmatrix}$. $M_{R}$ is reflection matrix.

I'd like to know **reflection matrix about**

1. $y=\tan \theta \cdot x$. Quick search in Google gives $(A) \begin{pmatrix}
   \cos{2\theta} & \sin{2\theta} \\ 
   \sin{2\theta} & -\cos{2\theta}
   \end{pmatrix}$. I inserted $(A)$ because I'm worry the right-side matrix needs to be multiplied with $m$ gradient or other stuff presents here. $(A)$ is not matrix.
2. $y=\tan \theta \cdot x$ when the reference point is not the origin.
3. $y=-\tan \theta \cdot x$. Should I just give negative sign to
   $\begin{pmatrix}
   \cos{2\theta} & \sin{2\theta} \\ 
   \sin{2\theta} & -\cos{2\theta}
   \end{pmatrix}$?
4. $y=-\tan \theta \cdot x$ when the reference point is not the origin (not $(0,0)$).
5. $y=mx$ when the reference point is not the origin. I already have $y=mx$ when the reference point is $(0,0)$.
6. $y=mx+c$.
7. $y=mx+c$ when the reference point is not the origin. The baseline formula must be needs $+\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ c \end{pmatrix}$ but I'm not sure.

Detail help is appreciated! Thanks.